# WF4 are the bookmarks stored on server or client side

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am currently working on a project where we are planning on using WF4 services. We also need to save the workflow progression by using bookmarks.
Are the bookmarks in WF4 stored on client or server side?
and is it a way to decide where it is saved ?

Answer (score 1):

After a few refined Google searches I found the answer to my question on MSDN.
Bookmarks are stored in the persistant store on the host/server side.

In order to store the bookmark on the client side I need to extend the abstract class InstanceStore. then stream/save the file(xml) to the client.

I will make sure to have at least 1 cup of coffe the next time I ask a question.

ref:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee829481(v=vs.110).aspx